# Rewrites ending with a known extension fails, why?

Tags: nginx

I have a rewrite that routes everything to my `index.php` file, however, if the url ends with a known extension (e.g: `.gif`, `.png`) it fails and gived a nginx 404 error page. How come?

My rewrite looks like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

This url works `domain.com/attachment/53c386a876a56_ets2_00000` and is using the `index.php` file.

This does NOT work `domain.com/attachment/53c386a876a56_ets2_00000.png` and gives a 404 Not Found nginx error.

Why doesn't it get sent to my `index.php` when I have a known extension in the url?

Comment: Please post your full config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a `location` block picking up those extensions and thus breaking the rewrite.

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
       add_header        Cache-Control public;
       add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
       expires           7d;
       access_log off;
}
```

I commented that out it now it works as it should.

Thanks @Tan Hong Hat.